# fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression when using "#if (false)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, boolean

Have following code which is working under Linux but gives error for MSVS

```
#if (false)
....
#endif
```

The error is: fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression

I found this report on Microsoft's web:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5sh3k99.aspx

While the info described there differs a little bit compared to my case as I didn't use the "#define"

So my question is:

1. Is there any way to make it working for MSVC without changing code ?
2. If the code must be updated, what's the best solution for this kind of case?

Comment: "as I didn't use the "#define"" -- How about any headers you included? Does it fail the same way if you don't include any headers?

Comment: Preprocessor doesn't know anything about `false` or other keywords - those are for the compiler. Preprocessor only knows about macro names and literals. Make it `#if 0`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's correct for C, but incorrect for C++ (which this question is about).

Comment: @hvd Igor's comment is not about what's true in C as opposed to what's true in C++.  It's about what's true in Phase 4 as opposed to what's not true in Phase 4.  `false` is a keyword in C++, but not during phase 4, where, to quote the standard, "all identifiers either are or are not macro names--there simply are no keywords, enumeration constants, etc".

Comment: @HWalters That is a note. The normative text specifically makes two exceptions: "After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, **except for `true` and `false`**, are replaced with the pp-number `0`, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token." That converting of pp-tokens into tokens then happens just as it does outside `#if` expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your version of MS compiler does not support false as a built-in constant. This is not surprising, because Microsoft has a spotty record of supporting standards for C and C++.

One way to make this work without changing the code is to pass command-line parameters to the compiler to define false as 0 and true as 1:

```
-Dfalse=0 -Dtrue=1
```

Comment: It only fails if MS doesn't support `false` in `#if` expressions, *and* has the special C++ rule where `false` is left as-is in `#if` expressions. In C, where `false` is not a keyword, `#if (false)` is just peachy: `false` gets replaced by `0`. (Ditto for `#if (true)` or `#if (aowehfbwa)`, for that matter.) Hence my comment on the question: I have a little bit more faith than you that MS didn't screw up *that* badly. :)

Comment: Testing shows that even that little bit of faith I still had was totally undeserved. Your answer is correct. I'm worried about the possibility of your definitions of `false` and `true` messing up overload resolution though. Some alternative that leaves them as constants of type `bool` outside of `#if` directives would be better, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @hvd Isn't this UB anyway (as explained in my answer?

Comment: @Columbo Assuming standard library headers get included, then yes, the behaviour is not defined by the standard. But *not* defining `true` and `false` as macros is also not defined by the standard: the standard does not describe the behaviour of programs on implementations that do not conform to the standard. It's a matter of picking the lesser evil.

Comment: I would change that to `-Dfalse=(!1)` and `-Dtrue=(!0)` to support `typeid` and overload resolution. In addition, the/some system headers of modern Visual C++ perform a check of whether keywords have been defined. That needs to be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to make it working for MSVC without changing code ?

Not really. Defining a macro for `false` is forbidden by the standard for good reasons, [macro.names]/2:

> A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically
>   identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the
>   *attribute-tokens* described in 7.6.

And I don't see any other way.

> If the code must be updated, what's the best solution for this kind of
>   case?

Substitute `0` for `false`.